# Using SQL in a function

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to create a function in PHP that connects to SQL with the global $conn, and another which authenticates the user. However, referencing the SQL connection function in the second function isn't working.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /[...]/functions.php on line [see below]
```

SQLinfo.php contains valid database information, in the form of constants SQLurl, SQLuser, SQLpass & SQLdatabase.

Code:

```
  function SQLconnect(){
    require 'SQLinfo.php';
    global $conn;
      $conn = new mysqli(SQLurl,SQLuser,SQLpass,SQLdatabase);
    if($conn->connect_error){
      return $conn->connect_error;
    }else{
      return True;
    }
  }


  function isauthenticated($username,$token){
    if(empty($username) || empty($token)){
        return False;
    }else{
      SQLconnect();
        //error line:
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `lastid` = '".$token."'");
        if($result->num_rows == 1){
            return True;
        }else{
            return False;
        }
    $result->free;
    }
  }
```

I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387485/functions-sql-connects-and-global-variable) answer, however since the mysql extension is deprecated and the global has been defined I couldn't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Because scope. You have to pass the connection into the second function.

Comment: Have you tried examining the return from that function since you do return the error if there is a connection error. Programming 101, if a function returns something then test it.

Comment: Why is this tagged `sql-server`?

Comment: Makes for cleaner breath @JayBlanchard

Comment: And gracious goodness knows that I need cleaner breath, especially at the end of the day @Fred-ii-

Comment: Have the SQLconnect return `$conn`, then you can pass it to any function that needs to use the database (i.e the `isAuthenticated` method).

Comment: *Goodness, gracious... great balls of fire!* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: @DaveChen, thank you. This worked great. Sorry SQL guys, new to Stack Overflow and didn't know tagging had such a big effect.